# Java SE get hard disk driver names

Tags: java, file

How to get hard disk driver names? 
For example I have two drives C and D, so how can I get their names?
I've tried `FileSystemView.getRoots()`, but it returns user work directory, like 'C:\Users\user_name'

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
    for(File f : File.listRoots()) {
        System.out.println(f);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`File` provides that. See the java [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listRoots%28%29)

```
File[] roots = File.listRoots();
```